# Min-max normalization with SQL using DB::raw in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel

Suppose I have a `User` model with the following data set

```
id | name | logged_in | login_disabled | last_login
---------------------------------------------------
1  | John |     0     |       1        | 1522139454
2  | Jane |     1     |       0        | 1522139124
3  | Ian  |     1     |       0        | 1522138722
```

I would like to get a collection of the logged in, non-login-disabled users with a max-min normalized last_login. Ideally I would use SQL to normalize the results as opposed to getting the users then calculating the normalization in PHP.

I have a scope query to get the logged-in, non-login-disabled users called `available` which I can access via `User::available()` which I would like to chain to get the max-min normalized `last_login` data.

I have tried this so far:

```
    $users = User::available()
                ->select(
                    \DB::raw(
                        "1.00 * ( t.last_login - t.min_last_login ) / t.login_range as normalized_login
                        FROM (
                            SELECT
                                last_login,
                                MIN(last_login) AS min_last_login,
                                MAX(last_login) - MIN(last_login) AS login_range,
                            FROM
                                users
                            ) t
                        "
                    )
                )
                ->get();
```

But this is throwing an SQL error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
>                                users
>                            ) t
>          ' at line 7 (SQL:

The raw SQL getting executed is:

```
select 1.00 * ( t.last_login - t.min_last_login ) /
       t.login_range as normalized_login
                     FROM (
                         SELECT
                             last_login,
                             MIN(last_login) AS min_last_login,
                             MAX(last_login) - MIN(last_login) AS login_range,
                         FROM
                             users
                         ) t
                      from `users` where `logged_in` = 1 and  `disabled` = 0
```

The raw SQL does look a bit off but I can't quite work out how to fit it in with the `select` method in the Laravel query builder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have an extra `comma` (`,`) after the last column in your `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT
    last_login,
    MIN(last_login) AS min_last_login,
    MAX(last_login) - MIN(last_login) AS login_range,
                                here is your culprit^
```

Because of that, it is then expecting another column to be selected. That's why you get the syntax error:

> 'FROM users ) t  at line 7 (SQL:'

Comment: Hi @KaeL thanks for your reply. You're absolutely right, that was the issue causing the error. I've fixed that but it's now throwing another error:
`Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from `users` where `logged_in` = 1 ...` Any ideas? Is it an issue with the declaration of alias table `t` ?

Comment: Hello @dbatten you only have the `users` table inside the `subquery`. You have to include the `users` table in the same level with your `where` clause by using `join` techniques, or you can move the `where` clause inside the `subquery` depending on your needs :)

Comment: Aha, thought I might have to get some joins involved, thanks for your help @kael

Comment: No problem mate!